# How to make an Async method keep running while a WinForm is open?

Tags: c#, winforms, azure-cognitive-services

I am working on a test project and I want the form to be able to write whatever i say in the textbox. At first I tried using Windows Speech but it was so bad that it coundn't even get a single word right. Then I switched to `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`, but now when I'm trying the function to keep running it just works the first time I say something and then stops working.

I even tried maving the `form1_Load` function `async` but that didn't work either.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;

namespace Project_01
{
    public partial class form1 : Form
    {
        public form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 

        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                textBox2.Focus();
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && textBox2.Text != "")
            {
                button1_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void OutputSpeechRecognitionResult(SpeechRecognitionResult speechRecognitionResult)
        {
            switch (speechRecognitionResult.Reason)
            {
                case ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
                    textBox1.Text = speechRecognitionResult.Text;
                    break;
                case ResultReason.NoMatch:
                    textBox1.Text = "NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.";
                    break;
                case ResultReason.Canceled:
                    var cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(speechRecognitionResult);
                    textBox1.Text = cancellation.Reason.ToString();
                    break;
            }
        }

        private async Task FirstMethod()
        {
            var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("Azure key", "Region");
            speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

            var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
            var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

            var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            OutputSpeechRecognitionResult(speechRecognitionResult);
        }

        private async void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await FirstMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

How can I keep the `FirstMethod()` working until the form is closed enabling it to detect and write anything I say at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private async Task FirstMethod()
{
    while (true)
    {
        var speechConfig = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("Azure key", "Region");
        speechConfig.SpeechRecognitionLanguage = "en-US";

        var audioConfig = AudioConfig.FromDefaultMicrophoneInput();
        var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(speechConfig, audioConfig);

        var speechRecognitionResult = await speechRecognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
        OutputSpeechRecognitionResult(speechRecognitionResult);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [continuous recognition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-csharp#use-continuous-recognition). You must subscribe to an event first

```
speechRecognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
{
    if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZED: Text={e.Result.Text}");
    }
    else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
    }
};
```

When subscribed, start recognition.

```
await speechRecognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
```